# Beginners python. Best way to store different amount of items for each key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I'm a beginner at programming (and also an older person), so I don't really know how to express what I want correctly. I've tried to describe my question as thoroughly as possible, so really appreciate your patience!

I would like to store the winning scores associated with each user.

- Each user would have different number of winning scores.
- I do not need to seperate users first name and last name, they can all be one string.
- I do not need the scores to be ordered in any way, and I don't need to be able to change them.
- I only need to be able to add the scores whenever the user wins and sort users by amount of wins.
- I will extract all the winning scores for statistics, but the statistics will not be concerned with what score belongs to what user.
- Once the program stops, it can all be erased from memory.

From what I've researched so far it seems my best options are to either create a user class, where I store a list and add to the list each time. Or to create a dictionary with a key for each user. But since each user may have a different amount of winning scores, I don't know if I can use dictionaries with that (unless each key is associated with a list maybe?). I don't think I need something like a numpy array, since I want to create very simple statistics without worrying about what score belongs to what user. 
I need to think about not using an unnecessary amount of memory etc., especially because there may be a hundred winning scores for each user. But I can't really find clear information on what the benefits of dictionaries vs classes are. The programming community is amazingly helpful and full of answers, but unfortunately I often don't understand the answers.

Greatful for any help I can get! And don't be afraid to tell me my ideas are dumb, I want to learn how to think like a programmer.

Comment: There is no problem with using a dictionary with list values. dictionaries are actually very efficient in python and used everywhere "under the hod" (also in classes). My first approach would be using a plain dictionary with score lists as values. If you need more flexibility later you could then switch to a custom class with additional functionality. Maybe you find this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npw4s1QTmPg) about the topic interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question because it discusses two possible solutions. The class based solution and the dictionary based solution. The class based solution is more elegant and versatile so I will describe that one.

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, scores, name): #Where scores is a list of their scores
        self.scores = scores
        self.name = name

    def get_scores(self):
        return self.scores

    def get_sum(self):
        return sum(self.scores)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
```

Then you could do something like

```
user_a = User([1,2,3], "Jerry Stewart")
user_b = User([1,3,12,13,110], "Godric Gryffindor")
user_c = User([8,10,11], "Jackie")
users = [user_a, user_b, user_c]

for user in users:
    print "{} : {}".format(user.get_name(), user.get_sum())
```

Hopefully this covers the basics of what you need!

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful! I did not know of this format function, so I've learned even more than I asked for!

Comment: I'm really glad that helped! The format method of Strings is incredibly useful! If you haven't already you can find the full documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

Building on Hallsville3's answer, I think you could achieve a similar outcome by simply subclassing list like so:

```
class User(list):
    def __init__(self, name, scores):
        super().__init__(scores)
        #Where scores is a list of their scores. This assumes you are using Python 3. Super calls in python 2 need a couple more arguments.
        self.name = name
```

Then you can create a list of users and add to it easily:

```
user_base = []
user_base.append(User('Stuart', [1, 2, 3]))
user_base.append(User('Jane', [4, 5, 6]))
```

This data model has only two layers Userlist => Scorelist/User Object, as opposed to having Userlist => User Object => Scorelist, which should make accessing it slightly simpler.

You can also expand your object to return statistics per user:

```
class User(list):
    def __init__(self, name, scores):
        super().__init__(scores)
        self.name = name
    @property
    def average(self):
        return sum(self)/len(self)
```

And use this to return all the users averages:

```
[user.average for user in user_base]
```

There are literally thousands of ways to structure your data, from simple implementations like this, up to SQL databases if you are doing this on a big scale. I think it makes sense to start with a simple model then buiild up complexity as you build up your skills.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dictionary` as values in dicts can be `mutable` like a `list` where you can keep all the scores/winning scores for each user.

`{'player1' : [22,33,44,55],
'player2' : [23,34,45],
.....
}`

If this is not an exercise that you will repeat dicts make sense but if it is an exercise that might need to be done again in future `Classes` are better alternative as explained in other answers by Stuart and Hallsville3.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is already an answer covering the class option, I give the simplest dictionary base solution I could come up with.
I personally would prefer to use a plain dictionary approach first and maybe switch to a more flexible class implementation later if it is needed.

A basic scores dictionary and its usage could look like this:

```
scores = {}

scores["user1"] = []  # empty scores list
scores["user2"] = [14, 32, 67]
scores["user3"] = [1, 94]

scores["user1"].append(45)  # add a single score
scores["user3"].extend([13, 22])  # add multiple scores

for user, user_scores in scores.items():
    print(user, user_scores, min(user_scores), max(user_scores), sum(user_scores))
```

Output for this would look like this:

```
user1 [45] 45 45 45
user2 [14, 32, 67] 14 67 113
user3 [1, 94, 13, 22] 1 94 130
```

Maybe you could experiment with this approach and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Yes this addition is very helpful, thank you! You made me realize something; I've only imagined a scenario of a handful users at best. But there should be no such restrictions. If I may trouble you with another question: what is the best practice if you were to have a list of one hundred users? Is it better to create a dictionary then? In my mind, I imagine creating a class instance for each user will take a lot of memory, but perhaps that is just because the code of the class _looks_ less efficient compared to a dictionary.

Comment: I think you have to try and measure like always when you try to optimise something. One hundred users should not be a problem. A dictionary is perfectly fine even for millions of users with thousands of scores. There is also a way to implement more memory efficient classes using [__slots__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) but i have no idea how it would compare to the plain dictionary approach in memory usage. I would strive for the simplest solution first and optimise only if I had a real memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

class is used when there is both state and behavior . dict is used when there's only state. since you have both  use class.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, all you need is a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a `list` as default.

```
from collections import defaultdict

scores = defaultdict(list)
scores['User1'].append(3)
scores['User1'].append(5)
scores['User2'].append(6)
scores['User2'].append(1)

print(scores)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'User1': [3, 5], 'User2': [6, 1]})

print(sorted(scores, key= lambda k: sum(scores[k]), reverse=True))
# ['User1', 'User2']

print(sorted(scores, key= lambda k: sum(scores[k])/len(scores[k]), reverse=True))
# ['User1', 'User2']
```

If each user has only one score, you could use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).